# How to insert data to phpMyAdmin database using Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add some data to my localhost database through a Bootstrap modal. I'm coding using Laravel 5.2.

This is my PHP function:

```
public function reportPost(Request $request) {
    $postreport = new postreport();
    $postreport->PostId = input::get('id');
    $postreport->UserId = session()->get('userid');
    $postreport->reasonId = $_POST('optradio');
    $postreport->save();
    return redirect('posts');
}
```

And this is my modal markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Tell Us What's Going On ?</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="reportPost" data-ajax="1">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;it's not interesting</label><br>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;I think it should not in our website</label><br>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;it's a spam</label><br>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="report_post" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing is added to my database. I watched many tutorials with no solution to my case.

Comment: Are you getting the form data into your controller?

Comment: `action="reportPost"` is that a folder holding an index file? If not, you need to point it to a php file.

Comment: How have you defined your route for this action? Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan i can't understand

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is a function in a controller

Comment: @Muhammed Ehab, Have you create postreport Model?

Comment: @manian yes i've defined my route it doesn't throw errors

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan done :D

Comment: @Muhammed Ehab Use dd($request->all()), does it shows something?

Comment: Can you print $postreport before save command & see what it returns. Also have you defined all the fillable fields in your Model?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan doesn't show anything :D the modal just dismissed

Comment: @Muhammed Ehab, it means that you are not getting your form data into your controller function. Show your route code also

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Route::post('reportPost','PostsAjaxController@reportPost');

Comment: echo some code into your function to check either you are going to your function or not after submitting form.

Comment: it doesn't read my postreport class giving me this error

    Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Be_Olympics\app\postreport.php on line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bootstrap model is used, data can not be saved directely through php(Laravel 5.2). In between jquery ajax or javascript ajax will come into play.

Solution is given step by step......

**First Step:**
In routes.php file

```
Route::post('/modal-test',[
  'uses' => 'TestController@modal_test',
  'as' => 'modal-test'
]);
```

**Second step:** 
In View file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Tell Us What's Going On ?</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                       <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;it's not interesting</label><br>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;I think it should not in our website</label><br>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;it's a spam</label><br>



                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="hello"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="report_post" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/juqery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').focus()
        });
    });
</script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#report_post').on('click',function(){
                console.log('clicked');
                var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
                var process = "{{ route('modal-test') }}";
                var radio_input = $('input:radio[name=optradio]:checked').val();;
               // console.log(radio_input);


                var data = {
                    "_token":token,
                    "radio_input":radio_input
                }
                $.post(process, data, function(result){
                    console.log(result);


                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**Third Step:** 
In Controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
class TestController extends Controller
{

public function modal_test(Request $request){
   $radio_input = $request->radio_input;

    DB::table('modal_input')->insert(
        ['radio_input' => $radio_input]
    );
    echo "Data inserted Successfully";
}
}
 ?>
```

Hopefully, It will be workable.